# 'Capture GPU frame' first frame for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

My application performs several rendering operations on the first frame (I am using Metal, although I think the same applies to GLES). For example, it renders to targets that are used in subsequent frames, but not updated after that. I am trying to debug some of draw calls from these rendering operations, and I would like to use the 'GPU Capture Frame' functionality to do so. I have used it in the past for on-demand GPU frame debugging, and it is very useful.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to capture the first frame. For example, this option is unavailable when broken in the debugger (setting a breakpoint before the first frame). The Xcode behaviors also don't seem to allow for capturing the frame once debugging starts. There also doesn't appear to even be an API for performing GPU captures, in Metal APIs or the CAMetalLayer.

Has anybody done this successfully?

Answer (score 7):

I've come across this again, and figured it out properly now. I'll add this as a separate answer, since it's a completely different approach from my other answer.

First, some background. There are three components to capturing a GPU frame:

1. Telling *Xcode* that you want to capture a GPU frame. In typical documented use, you do this   manually by clicking the *GPU Frame Capture* "camera" button in *Xcode*.
2. Indicating the ***start*** of the next frame to capture. Normally, this occurs at the *next* occurrence of `MTLCommandBuffer presentDrawable:`, which is invoked to present the framebuffer to the underlying view.
3. Indicating the ***end*** of the frame being captured. Normally, this occurs at the *next-but-one* occurrence of `MTLCommandBuffer presentDrawable:`.

In capturing the ***first*** frame, or activity *before* the first frame, only the third of these is available, so we need an alternate way to perform the first two items:

1. To tell *Xcode* to begin capturing a frame, add a breakpoint in *Xcode* at a line in your code somewhere *before* the point at which you want to start capturing a frame. Right-click the breakpoint, select ***Edit Breakpoint...*** from the pop-up menu, and add a *Capture GPU Frame* action to the breakpoint:

   [image]
2. To indicate the start of the frame to capture, *before* the first occurrence of `MTLCommandBuffer presentDrawable:`, you can use the `MTLCommandQueue insertDebugCaptureBoundary` method. For example, you could invoke this method as soon as you instantiate the `MTLCommandQueue`, to immediately begin capturing everything submitted to the queue. Make sure the breakpoint in *item 1* will be triggered before the point this code is invoked.
3. To indicate the end of the captured frame, you can either rely on the first normal occurrence of `MTLCommandBuffer presentDrawable:`, or you can add a second invocation of `MTLCommandQueue insertDebugCaptureBoundary`.

Finally, the `MTLCommandQueue insertDebugCaptureBoundary` method does not actually cause the frame to be captured. It just marks a boundary point, so you can leave it in your code for future debugging use. Wrap it in a `DEBUG` compilation conditional if you want it gone from production code.

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
[myMTLCommandEncoder insertDebugSignpost: @"com.apple.GPUTools.event.debug-frame"].
```

To be honest, I haven't tried it myself, but it's analogous to the similar

```
glInsertEventMarkerEXT(0, "com.apple.GPUTools.event.debug-frame")
```

documented for OpenGL ES, and there is some mention on the web of it working for Metal.

Comment: looked promising, but doesn't seem to work for Metal, at least, not for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Metal, I usually use Metal to do parallel compute, then GPU Capture frame is alway grey. So, there are two ways until now I found is Ok.

1. In iOS 11

   you can use the `[[MTLCaptureManager alloc] startCaptureWithDevice:m_Device];` to capture frame so you can profile the compute shader performance
2. lower than iOS 11 (MTLCaptureManager && MTLCaptureScope are new in iOS 11.0 )
   you can use the breakpoint, then edit the Action.`Capture GPU Frame`